# How do I change a Gtk3 Entry text color in Python3?

Tags: python, gtk3, python-3.2

I have a list of `Gtk.Entry()` in my application, and I would like to change the color of the text of some of them.

I tried the following :

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# Filename: mywindow.py

from gi.repository import Gtk
from gi.repository import Gdk

class MyWindow(Gtk.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title="My window")

        self.mainGrid = Gtk.Grid()
        self.add(self.mainGrid)

        self.myOkEntry = Gtk.Entry()
        self.myOkEntry.set_text("This is OK (green)")
        self.myOkEntry.override_color(Gtk.StateFlags.NORMAL, Gdk.RGBA(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0))

        self.mainGrid.add(self.myOkEntry)

mainWin = MyWindow()
mainWin.connect("delete-event", Gtk.main_quit)
mainWin.show_all()

Gtk.main()
```

But then the text was invisible. I tried different values for Gdk.RGBA from 0.0 to 1.0, and from 0 to 65000, it was the same. 
Another test :

```
print(Gdk.color_parse("green"))
```

prints :

```
<Gdk.Color(red=0, green=65535, blue=0)>
```

So I tried :

```
print(Gdk.RGBA(Gdk.color_parse("green")))
```

But :

```
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gi/overrides/Gdk.py", line 55, in __init__
    self.red = red
TypeError: argument 2: Must be number, not Color
```

I'm a bit confused.
The documentations I use are mainly: 
https://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.org/en/latest/
https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/

I found some documentation about CSS styling, can I use it like :

```
GtkEntry {
    color: #000000
}
GtkEntry#ok {
    color: #00cc00
}
GtkEntry#error {
    color: #cc0000
}
```

Like in HTML for instance ? This documentation was linked in a previous question about `Python3/Gtk3` [Entry color](http://erikos.sweettimez.de/2011/11/23/gtk-3-theme-style-your-applications/)

Well, my question is : how can I change the text color of one Gtk.Entry() without modifying the color of the others ?

Comment: Maybe this can get you in the right direction? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13187207/setting-selected-property-of-row-in-treeview-dynamically-in-gtk3-python

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set the alpha channel to 1.0:

```
self.myOkEntry.override_color(Gtk.StateFlags.NORMAL, Gdk.RGBA(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [gtk.Widget.modify_fg](https://developer.gnome.org/pygtk/stable/class-gtkwidget.html#method-gtkwidget--modify-fg) (Widget being one of the base classes for gtk.Entry) with your color_parse logic like so:

```
self.myOkEntry.modify_fg(Gtk.StateFlags.NORMAL, Gdk.color_parse("green"))
```

Comment: In the GTK3 documentation of this method :

    gtk_widget_modify_fg has been deprecated since version 3.0 and should not be used in newly-written code. Use gtk_widget_override_color() instead.

So I will use modify_fg() for now, but I'm looking for a standard Gtk3 solution.

Comment: @JeanCoiron DeprecationWarning: Gtk.Widget.override_color is deprecated

Comment: Both of these answers worked for me. The first (self.myOkEntry.override_color(Gtk.StateFlags.NORMAL, Gdk.RGBA(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0))) being of lighter, true RGB green. The second was a little darker.