# Gtk. widget - can't change bg color. Pygtk

Tags: python, colors, gtk, pygtk

I writing gtk interface with python code. the problem is:

init entry widget by gtkbuilder:

`self.some_entry = self.builder.get_object('SomeEntry')`

Define signal by typing button, after then must changed entry color:

`def on_SomeButton_clicked(self, widget):
     self.some_entry.modify_bg(Gtk.StateType.NORMAL,Gdk.Color(20000,10000,10000))`

but it doesn't work, such 'modify_base'. And  I don't know why. Help please.
Sorry for my English(

Comment: with GtkTextView it works, but it gtkwidget too

Comment: it seems to be like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15245886/how-do-i-change-a-gtk3-entry-text-color-in-python3 but background instead, and override_background_color(Gtk.StateFlags.NORMAL, Gdk.RGBA(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0)) didn't help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT2:
Turns out it was an entry box giving the problem which is another issue in and of itself because the background is not the property you need to modify but the BASE color property which can typically be set using:

```
self.entry.override_background_color(Gtk.StateType.Normal, Gdk.RGBA(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0))
```

However for OP it was not working so a CSS option was explored, listed at: https://mail.gnome.org/archives/gtk-app-devel-list/2005-November/msg00236.html

EDIT:
So working with PyGtk3 I was able to get a button changing color using you line of code:

```
self.button.modify_bg(Gtk.StateType.Normal, Gdk.Color(20000, 10000, 10000))
```

It was grey on initialization and dark red after the code ran. The only thing I could think of is make sure that the object you are trying to modify is actually in a NORMAL state after you run the code and make sure the signal you think is triggering is actually triggering.

==============

Original post:

Without having the full code here there are a few things that could be causing this. I just threw together a test program in Python based off of: http://pygtk.org/pygtk2tutorial/examples/helloworld.py

When I set the Gtk State for the modify_bg I had to use:

```
gtk.STATE_NORMAL
```

Not sure if that is due to a different version of Gtk or what though.
Then when I went to use Gdk I had to refer to it as:

```
gtk.gdk
```

The line that I ended up with to change the button color was:

```
self.button.modify_bg(gtk.STATE_NORMAL, gtk.gdk.Color(20000, 10000, 10000))
```

Hopefully that works out, in order to get any more detailed though we would definitely need more code and to know what kind of errors you are getting.

Comment: Thanks, but it usefull fot another version.

Comment: I use gtk3 & python3. I have been looking for documentation a long time, because gtk.STATE_NORMAL - old type, and it doesn't work for me.

Comment: And yes, there are no warnings in my program at work.

Comment: There arу actual code: http://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/#Gdk-3.0/structs/Color.html#Gdk.Color http://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/#Gtk-3.0/enums.html#Gtk.StateType

Comment: The links you gave are to the documentation not the actual code, I read the documentation and updated my response.

Comment: Thats the problem, I think:  "the object you are trying to modify is actually in a NORMAL state..." but nothing similar. I confused, really.

Comment: Try modifying the bg for other states and see what happens, try modifying other backgrounds and try printing something in your callback where this modify_bg is being called to ensure that your callback is being run, without your code though there is no way to know what is happening for sure.

Comment: self.text_view = self.builder.get_object("DescTextView")
self.text_view.override_background_color(Gtk.StateFlags.NORMAL, Gdk.RGBA(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0)) it works

Comment: self.text_view.modify_bg(Gtk.StateType.NORMAL, Gdk.Color(20000,10000,10000)) and it works too

Comment: only gtk.entry gave the problem

Comment: See that changes everything, posting more code helps you get to the root of the problem quicker.


In order to change the bg color of Gtk.Entry you must use the override_background_color method as you did with your text_view object.

Comment: There is also an option to use CSS to set the style of the object using the BASE property as outlined here: https://mail.gnome.org/archives/gtk-app-devel-list/2005-November/msg00236.html

Answer (score 1):

CSS works, code below:

```
style_provider = Gtk.CssProvider()
    css = open('style.css', 'rb')
    css_data = css.read()
    css.close()
    style_provider.load_from_data(css_data)
    Gtk.StyleContext.add_provider_for_screen(
        Gdk.Screen.get_default(),
        style_provider,
        Gtk.STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIORITY_APPLICATION)
```

With line

> "widgetname".get_style_context().add_class("colorize")

"widgetname" has been colorized.

CSS code:

```
.colorize {

           background: rgba(200,50,50,0.3);
}
```